# Submitting id value to cart page php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a products page with add to cart button and products have their own ids, and the ids echo correctly on this page. I want to pass this id values to the cart.php but when i click add to cart only the last product id in my database is submitted. I have a select statement to ensure not to add same product twice in the cart.

My products page:

```
 <form method="POST" action="action.php">
            <?php 
            require_once 'db.php';
            try {
            $STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM products");
            $STH->execute();

            $rows_affected = $STH->rowCount();
            if ($rows_affected > 0){
                while($row = $STH->fetch()){
                    $pro_id    = $row['product_id'];
                    $pro_cat   = $row['product_cat'];
                    $pro_image = $row['product_image'];
                    $cat_name = $row["cat_title"];

                    echo "
                    <input type='hidden' class='form-control' name='product_id' value='$pro_id' required>
                    <input type='hidden' class='form-control' name='qty' value='1' required>
                    <div class='product'>
                       <a href='product.php?p=$pro_id'><div class='product-img'>
                       <img src='product_images/$pro_image' style='max-height: 170px;' alt=''>
                       </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class='product-body'>
                    <p class='product-category'>$cat_name</p>
                    <h3 class='product-name header-cart-item-name'><a href='product.php?p=$pro_id'>$pro_title</a></h3>
                    <div class='product-btns'>
                    <button class='addToCart' name='addToCart'><i class='fa fa-shopping-cart'></i><span class='tooltipp'>Add to cart</span></button>
                    
             </div> 
                        
                    ";
                }
    ;
                        
                    }
                    ?>
                        
                        <?php
                                    }
                                catch(PDOException $e){
                                    $_SESSION['error'] = "Couldn't fetch the products";
                                    file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND); # log errors to afile
                                }
                                ?>
```

My cart.php/ action.php in the form action is like:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['addToCart'])) {
    $p_id = $_POST["product_id"];
    $user_id = $_SESSION["uid"];

    try{
        if(isset($_SESSION["uid"])){

            $user_id = $_SESSION["uid"];
            $STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM cart WHERE p_id = ? AND user_id = ?");
            $data = array($p_id,$user_id);
            $STH -> execute($data);

            $rows_affected = $STH->rowCount();
            if ($rows_affected > 0){
                echo "
                <div class='alert alert-warning'>
                        <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>
                <b>Product is already added into the cart Continue Shopping..!</b>
                </div>
            ";
            header('refresh:2; url=index.php');
            } else {
                $qty=$_POST['qty'];
                $STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO cart(p_id, ip_add, user_id,qty) values(?,?,?,?)");
                $data = array($p_id,$ip_add,$user_id,$qty);
                $STH->execute($data); 
                
                echo "
                <div class='alert alert-warning'>
                        <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>
                        <b>Product Successfully added into the cart Continue Shopping..!</b>
                </div>
            ";
                header('refresh:2; url=index.php');
            }
        }   
            
    }  
?>
```

This will only add the last product in my products table and not add again because the product is in the cart. And when i clear the cart it will still insert the last product id. What am i missing?!

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed it:

changed the form from outside the loop to inside the loop
The hidden input types still remain
This surprisingly works for me. Gets to echo the correct product to action.php